# Pull emails from google Using token

Tags: node.js, email, imap, backend

I'm trying to pull email from Google using NodeJS. I have found several modules that do that, but all of them required the email and password.

For Example: [imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap)

I don't want to capture passwords from my users, I want to authenticate them on the front of my application and have a token that I could use to pull the emails in my backend. Is this possible to use a Google API that doesn't require the password to be used?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, and prominently described in the gmail documentation.

Comment: Yes, the technology you want is called OAuth2.